# Can't make bootstrap dropdown menu show and hide

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu show on hover and then go away. This code works partially, without the "setTimeout" it make all the changes but when i add the "setTimeout" the menu show and stay and doesn't go away until you hover it again. I've tried separating the functions and calling the ".dropdown" again with a ".blur" that hides it but it doesn't work neither.

In case you ask, I want to set the time because there is a little margin in which it loses hover so I just want to avoid someone who scroll slowly to get uncomfortable, it's only for user experience. I know I could modify the CSS to make it appear a bit up but I rather know how to do this for future issues.

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('show');
            var menu = $(this).children('.dropdown-menu');
            var arial = $(this).children('#navbarDropdown');
            $(arial).attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
            menu.toggleClass('show');
        }, 

        setTimeout(function() {
            var menu = $(this).children('.dropdown-menu');
            var arial = $(this).children('#navbarDropdown');
            $(this).removeClass('show');
            $(arial).attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
            menu.removeClass('show');
        }, 2000));
    }
);
```

Here is the Dropdown example:

```
<li id="drop" class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a> 
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Category 1</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Category 2</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Category 3</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Thanks for the help. In case anybody wonders, here is the end result:

```
$(document).ready( 
    function () {
        $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('show');
            var menu = $(this).children('.dropdown-menu');
            var arial = $(this).children('#navbarDropdown');
            arial.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
            menu.toggleClass('show');
        }, function () {
            var menu = $('.dropdown').children('.dropdown-menu');
            var arial = $('.dropdown').children('#navbarDropdown');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.dropdown').removeClass('show');
                arial.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
                menu.removeClass('show');   
            }, 400);    
        });                     
});
```

Comment: Could you share html and css either by a code snippet of codepen.

Comment: would you please add a Jsfiddle or add some HTML codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this)` cannot be used in the time function. Use `$('.dropdown')` instead.

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('show');
            var menu = $(this).children('.dropdown-menu');
            var arial = $(this).children('#navbarDropdown');
            arial.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
            menu.toggleClass('show');
        }, 

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.dropdown').removeClass('show');
            
            var menu = $(this).children('.dropdown-menu');
            var arial = $(this).children('#navbarDropdown');
            $(this).removeClass('show');
            arial.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
            menu.removeClass('show');
        }, 2000));
    }
);
```

It is also cleaner to use `arial` instead of `$(arial)` because `arial` is already a jQuery object, just like `menu`

Comment: thanks, it works, i had no idea i couldn't use $(this) in the time function. I will also change the varible names.